# How does Kotlin's `lazy` implementation work without getValue and setValue?

Tags: kotlin, properties, delegates

In Kotlin properties with pre-set custom get/set behavior are implemented using [delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html). According to the doc, a delegate for a property is just a class with `getValue` and `setValue` methods

But when I looked inside [the implementation of `lazy`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/f32c3551909f3e510d8d7c4821c3d52a10d3cc2b/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/util/LazyJVM.kt#L61), I only found `value` property. So I tried to implement a delegate this way myself. It failed to compile, because `getValue` and `setValue` were not implemented explicitly. How does the official implementation of `lazy` work then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getValue` is declared as an extension function (yes that works too!) on all `Lazy<T>`s:

[Source](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/6a670dc5f38fc73eb01d754d8f7c158ae0176ceb/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Lazy.kt#L44):

```
public inline operator fun <T> Lazy<T>.getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = value
```

As you can see, it returns `value`, which is exactly what you would expect.

There is no `setValue`, and that is fine. That just means you can't use `lazy { ... }` as a property delegate for a `var`, and you indeed cannot:

```
var foo by lazy { 10 } // compiler error
```

After all, this doesn't make much sense anyway.